# Parent Property Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

Have a ViewModel with two properties: Venue and States
Venue is the current view that is selected and being displayed via a form (below):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,00,0,0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" DataContext="{Binding Venue}">
            <TextBlock Text="Venue Name" Style="{StaticResource FormHeading}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtVenueName" Width="200" MaxLength="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding VenueName, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <TextBlock Text="Address" Style="{StaticResource FormHeading}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" Width="300" MaxLength="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <TextBlock Text="City" Style="{StaticResource FormHeading}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtCity" Width="200" MaxLength="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding City, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <TextBlock Text="State" Style="{StaticResource FormHeading}" />
            <ComboBox Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="cmbState" DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=States, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Zipcode" Style="{StaticResource FormHeading}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtZipCode" Width="50" MaxLength="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Zipcode, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Active?" Style="{StaticResource FormHeading}" Margin="0,0,10,0"  />
                <CheckBox Name="chkActive" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

States is not a member of Venue, however, but it is a property at the same level as Venue. How can I bind to this property? Looked at RelativeSource, doesnt seem to be quite what I am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're setting `DataContext={Binding Venue}`.  One option is to remove this and then alter the other bindings to be `Text="{Binding Venue.VenueName, ...}"` etc.  You could then use `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=States, ..."}`.

Alternatively a RelativeSource binding would work.  Something like:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=States, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"
```

depending on the type of the parent of the StackPanel obviously.

Comment: Good call. Not a big fan of look for ancestors as that couples the markup to itself, you ever change anything and forget, boom.  Thanks for the . notation, I had quite forgotten about it